# Seperate Web.Config file at Site Collection levels

Tags: 2013, site-collection, web-config

In SharePoint, Web.Config file is only one as per One Web Application.

Now,

I have a One Web Application, Inside it different site collections,
Now if i change something in web.config file it will applied all site collections,

**but my requirement is web.config should be different for each site collections, so modification in web.config applied particular site collections.**

Is it possible ?

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't have different web.config for different site collections, however you maybe be able to add tweaks e.g. [HttpModule and HttpHandlers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers) configurations to it depending on your requirements...

Answer (score 2):

You can not have different web.config for different site collection. If you have different configuration for each sitecollection it is better to use site collection property bag